# How do I find out what startup mechanism runs a docker container on system boot?

Tags: ubuntu, startup

I have ubuntu 22.04. There is a docker container that gets run on every boot. I probably put it there myself, but I don't remember where. I want this container not to run anymore. How do I find which configuration file is responsible for invoking it?

I looked at the usual places: the `crontab`, `/etc/cron.*` directories, `/etc/init.d` directory, `/etc/rc.local`, anything in the `/var/log`, but to no avail.

The problem is also that I am not sure how the container is started: via `docker run`, via `docker compose`, or via some helper script indirectly.

I read about `forkstat`, but it does not seem to be installed by default, it is not clear how to run it on boot early enough, and I am concerned about making the system unbootable.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

It was the docker daemon (dockerd) who restarted the container on reboot, because it was created with restart=always policy. That's why I could not find a specific command that would run it. Oh, well.

One can examine container restart policy by running
`docker inspect container_name` and looking for `RestartPolicy` item in the output.